# Is it possible to vectorize 3 nested for loops(3 total) when the inner 2 for loops parameters change with each iteration of the first main for loop?

Tags: matlab, performance, for-loop, nested, vectorization

All the examples and questions I have found on vectorization have dealt with static parameters. I have been successful at vectorizing such for loops in the past but am still a beginner. Primarily getting experience on programming exercises on Coursera's Machine Learning by Stanford University.

I could use help vectorizing code where the inner for loops parameters change with each iteration. My code loops over a two dimensional data set. A search area is determined for each data point in the set. Every data point in the search area that is with in a given radius will be used for a cumulative calculation.The search area size is different for each point; therefore, the two inner for loops will be of different sizes for each iteration.

[Each of the blues dots in this image represent a data point being traversed by the outer for loop. The magenta cross represents the current point being evaluated. There is one array for the points location and another array for the points data. The black rectangle is the search area for this point. The two inner for loops traverse each grid point in the search area. The grid points are defined by the tick marks on the plot that create a uniform Cartesian grid. The green circle highlights the current grid point being evaluated. Because the grid point is inside the magenta radius a convolution interpolation will be performed with data from the blue point(magenta cross hairs) and added to the current value at that grid point(initialized to zero).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WovDE.png)

[In this example the current grid point(red circle) is outside the radius(magenta circle) so nothing is done.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld4SD.png)

It is important to note in the examples above that each blue dot will only have one search area and only be used in one iteration of the outer for loop, but each grid point will be compared to all surrounding blue dots and the convolution interpolation will be added to their values when ever they are close enough(inside magenta circle) to a sample point(blue dot).

Is it possible to vectorize this code? Or is it impossible and I am just wasting time?

Here is a code example with irrelevant code removed and some variables changed for simplicity:

```
for loc_i = 1:length(dataLocations)

    xMin_i = floor(((xdata(loc_i)-searchRadius)));
    . . . condition check to set min here

    xMax_i = ceil(((xdata(loc_i)+searchRadius)));
    . . . condition check to set max here

    yMin_i = floor(((ydata(loc_i)-searchRadius)));
    . . . condition check to set min here

    yMax_i = ceil(((ydata(loc_i)+searchRadius)));
    . . . condition check to set max here
%
%--end search area boundary index determination-----------------------%

%--traverse the search area-------------------------------------------%
%
% nested for loops will traverse search area column by column starting
%   in the bottom left corner

% update output indexes to align with starting point of the current
%   search area
%   xMin_i * gridSize_n finds the current column
%   + yMin_i finds the current row
%

realOut_i = ((xMin_i) * gridSize_n + yMin_i); 
imagOut_i = ((xMin_i) * gridSize_n + yMin_i);

% update incrementer for output index to move to the starting point of
%   the next column within the search area
%
nxtCol_inc = gridSize_n - (yMax_i - yMin_i) - 1;

    % traverse columns of search area
    %
    for col_i = xMin_i:xMax_i

    % calculate x component of the distance vector between current
    %   trajectory point and current cartesian grid point
    %
    dx_n = col_i - (xTraj_d(loc_i ));


        % traverse rows of each search area
        %
        for row_i = yMin_i:yMax_i       

            % calculate y component of the distance vector between current
            %   trajectory point and current cartesian grid point
            %
            dy_n = row_i - (yTraj_d(loc_i));

            % calculate magnitude of the distance vector between the
            %   current trajectory point and the current cartesian grid 
            %   point
            %
            dk_n = sqrt(dx_n^2 + dy_n^2);

            if dk_n < searchRadius

                % determine where the grid point lies within the covolution
                %   radius, measured as the distance from the center
                %
                fractionKernel_i =...
                    (dk_n / (kernelRadius_n)*(kernTabPnts_n-1));

                % seperate the integer portion of the indexed distance to
                %   retrieve indexed values from the kernel table
                %
                integerKernel_i = floor(fractionKernel_i);

                % save the decimal portion of the indexed distance to
                %   weight the values retrieved from the kernel table
                % 
                %
                ratioKernel_n = fractionKernel_i - integerKernel_i;

                % determine kernel value for current grid point
                % value is linearly interpolated for precision
                % 
                %
                kernel = ...
                    kernelTable_d(integerKernel_i+1)*(1-ratioKernel_n)+...
                    kernelTable_d(integerKernel_i+2)*ratioKernel_n;

                % do convolution interpolation for real values
                %
                realOutput(realOut_i) = ...
                    realOutput(realOut_i) + ...
                    kernel*realSample_d(loc_i)*dcf(loc_i);

                % do convolution interpolation for imaginary values
                %
                imagOutput(imagOut_i) = ...
                    imagOutput(imagOut_i) +...
                    kernel*imagSample_d(loc_i)*dcf(loc_i);

            end % if dk_n < searchRadius

            % move to the next row in the search column
            %
            realOut_i = realOut_i + 1;
            imagOut_i = imagOut_i + 1;


        end % row_i = yMin_i:yMax_i

        % move to the starting point of the next column in the search area
        %
        realOut_i = realOut_i + nxtCol_inc;
        imagOut_i = imagOut_i + nxtCol_inc;

    end % col_i = xMin_i:xMax_i

    %-- finished traversing search area-----------------------------------%

end % for loc_i = 1:length(dataLocations)
```

Comment: I would suggest you start by vectorizing the inner two loops (why complicate things by vectorizing everything in one go?) However, since you don't show the computations you do there, we cannot help you. Please add more of the code, you have removed too much. Also, asking for external resources is out of scope for SO, you should remove that sentence if you don't want your question closed.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I removed the out of scope question and added some missing coded segments. I agree, vectorizing the two inner loops should be my focus.